# Memoir ToC Question

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In the ToC of a long document, I exclude chapter numbers in the text and ToC with a modification to the `bringhust` style as well as:

```
\setsecnumdepth{section}
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% no number for chapters in toc
```

In the latter part of the document, however, I'd like section numbers to appear in the text and the ToC... but WITHOUT the chapter numbers prefixed in either text or ToC. Can this be done? How?

In a feeble attempt to achieve that, I thought of this: reset the section counter with each feast date, then use the first optional argument of the `\section` for the date listed with the saint’s name and the the saint's name for the rest.

E.g.:

```
\chapter{January}
\setcounter{section}{16}
\section[— St. Antony the Great][]{St. Antony the Great}
```

This way, I can use the code from [`memman.pdf`](//texdoc.net/pkg/memoir) **9.2 ToC methods**, to set the section numbers flushright.

But those pesky chapter numbers are prefixed!!

Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{9in}{6in}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{.75in}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

%\tolerance=600
\hfuzz=1.2pt

\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vskip\onelineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\clearforchapter}{\cleartorecto}

\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \centering\Large\scshape{#1}}

\setsecnumdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% no number for chapters in toc

\setsecheadstyle{\centering\Large}

%%  from memman.pdf 9.2 ToC methods
% To set the section numbers flushright:
       \newlength\mylen
       \setlength{\mylen}{0.5em}% extra space at end of number
       \renewcommand{\cftsectionpresnum}{\hfill} % note the double ‘l’
       \renewcommand{\cftsectionaftersnum}{\hspace*{\mylen}}
       \addtolength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{\mylen}
       \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\hfill} % note the double ‘l’
       \renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\hspace*{\mylen}}
       \addtolength{\cftchapternumwidth}{\mylen}

\pagestyle{plain}

\raggedbottom
\frenchspacing


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{January}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section[— St. Paul the First Hermit, C][]{St. Paul the First Hermit, C}
\lipsum[10]
\setcounter{section}{14}
\section[— Our Lady of the Seeds][]{Our Lady of the Seeds}
\lipsum[14]
\setcounter{section}{15}
\section[— Memorial of the Chains of St. Peter the Apostle][]{Memorial of the Chains of St. Peter the Apostle}
\lipsum[15]
\setcounter{section}{16}
\section[— St. Antony the Great, C][]{St. Antony the Great, C}
\lipsum[16]
\setcounter{section}{22}
\section[— Pope St.Sergius I, C][]{Pope St.Sergius I, C}
\lipsum[17]
\setcounter{section}{23}
\section[— St. Francis de Sales, C][]{St. Francis de Sales, C}
\lipsum[18]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Something like `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` does what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the representation of the `section` counter for the latter part of your document in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

The default is to prefix it with `\thechapter`. Additionally, automate the process of adding the *emdash* to your ToC, since duplicating titles just for the sake of adding an *emdash* will lead to mistakes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{9in}{6in}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{.75in}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vskip\onelineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\clearforchapter}{\cleartorecto}

\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \centering\Large\scshape{#1}}

\setsecnumdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% no number for chapters in toc

\setsecheadstyle{\centering\Large}

%%  from memman.pdf 9.2 ToC methods
% To set the section numbers flushright:
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpresnum}{\hfill} % note the double ‘l’
\renewcommand{\cftsectionaftersnum}{~---~}
\addtolength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{1.5em}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{January}

\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{St.~Paul the First Hermit, C}
\lipsum[10]
\setcounter{section}{14}
\section{Our Lady of the Seeds}
\lipsum[14]
\setcounter{section}{15}
\section{Memorial of the Chains of St. Peter the Apostle}
\lipsum[15]
\setcounter{section}{16}
\section{St. Antony the Great, C}
\lipsum[16]
\setcounter{section}{22}
\section{Pope St.~Sergius I, C}
\lipsum[17]
\setcounter{section}{23}
\section{St. Francis de Sales, C}
\lipsum[18]

\chapter{February}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}%
\setcounter{section}{4}
\section{St.~Paul the First Hermit, C}
\lipsum[10]
\setcounter{section}{14}
\section{Our Lady of the Seeds}
\lipsum[14]
\setcounter{section}{15}
\section{Memorial of the Chains of St. Peter the Apostle}
\lipsum[15]
\setcounter{section}{16}
\section{St. Antony the Great, C}
\lipsum[16]
\setcounter{section}{22}
\section{Pope St.~Sergius I, C}
\lipsum[17]
\setcounter{section}{23}
\section{St. Francis de Sales, C}
\lipsum[18]

\end{document}
```