# Memoir ToC Followup

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Thanks to Luis and Werner for the solution. And I have a follow-up question.

Here's a new command to incorporate what goes into the feast days:

```
\newcommand\saint[2]{%
\needspace{8\onelineskip}%
\setcounter{section}{#1}%
\section[#2][]{\\ #2}%
}
```

But if the feast date is 10, when it types it into the text or ToC, it adds a number. Now I could try to remember to subtract a unit from each feast day ... but is  there some way with the code to take the data entered (e.g., 10) and subtract one from it to enter as the \setcounter number to use in the \saint definition? That would automate better and prevent more mistakes.

Below is another MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{9in}{6in}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{.75in}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{bringhurst}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
  \vskip\onelineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\clearforchapter}{\cleartorecto}

\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \centering\Large\scshape{#1}}

\setsecnumdepth{section}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{}% no number for chapters in toc

\setsecheadstyle{\centering\Large}

%%  from memman.pdf 9.2 ToC methods
% To set the section numbers flushright:
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpresnum}{\hfill} % note the double ‘l’
\renewcommand{\cftsectionaftersnum}{~—~}
\addtolength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{.5em}

\pagestyle{plain}
\frenchspacing

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}%

\newcommand\saint[2]{%
\needspace{8\onelineskip}%
\setcounter{section}{#1}%
\section[#2][]{\\ #2}%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{January}

\saint{5}{St.~Paul the First Hermit, C}
\lipsum[10]
\saint{15}{Our Lady of the Seeds}
\lipsum[14]
\saint{16}{Memorial of the Chains of St. Peter the Apostle}
\lipsum[15]
\saint{17}{St. Antony the Great, C}
\lipsum[16]
\saint{23}{Pope St.~Sergius I, C}
\lipsum[17]
\saint{24}{St. Francis de Sales, C}
\lipsum[18]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\addtocounter{section}{-1}% `  after `\setcounter{section}{#1}`

Comment: Thank you VERY much!!

Comment: Please link to your earlier question so people don't need to find it if they want to read the answers or original question.

Comment: Thank you for all the assistance. Since I don't have email, others assist me when they can. So at last, here's the link to the original question.

fr. mgc

original question link:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698184/memoir-toc-question